# How to access meteor call in Template event

Tags: meteor

I am making a meteor call and getting array in return on the client side.

I want to use this array in an event inside Template but the array is not recognized outside the meteor call.

How to access this array in a Template event?

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {   
        result=[];
        Meteor.call('getApiResult', function (err, result) {
            if (result) {
                console.log("reached meteor call")
                console.log(result);

            }
        });

     Template.dpVar.events = {
            'click .addproduct' : function  (err) {

                for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    var Temp_Name = result[i];
                    var Temp_Val = document.getElementById(Temp_Name).value
                    console.log("temp name is ", Temp_Name);
                    productDB.insert({ Temp_Name: Temp_Val});
                    console.log("temp val is ", Temp_Val);
                }

            }
}//Client Ends
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't setting `result`, you are overloading the name ;-)

Try this, if it doesn't work, move `result = []` into the global scope.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    result = [];
    Meteor.call('getApiResult', function (err, res) {
        if (res) {
            console.log("reached meteor call")
            console.log(res);
            result = res;
        }
    });

    Template.dpVar.events = {
        'click .addproduct' : function  (err) {         
            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var Temp_Name = result[i];
                var Temp_Val = document.getElementById(Temp_Name).value
                console.log("temp name is ", Temp_Name);
                productDB.insert({ Temp_Name: Temp_Val});
                console.log("temp val is ", Temp_Val);
            }

        }
    }
}
```